# Calculate transaction fee for send transaction on Arbitrum

Tags: ethers.js, fees, arbitrum

Trying to implement send transaction i already acknowledge that gasLimit != 21_000 for arbitrum so i also changed my approach having following script for estimating:

```
const [feeData, to] = await Promise.all([this.getFeeData(), this.getAccount()]);
const gasLimit = Number(await this.wallet.estimateGas({ to }));
const estimatedGas = BigNumber.from(feeData.maxFeePerGas).mul(gasLimit);
```

Which gives me at the current moment:

```
maxFeePerGas: 1200000000
estimateGas: 489733
```

and result from calculations is:

`0.0005876796` eth which at the current prices is around ~$1, just tested on metamask overthere fee is around ~$0.10. So what i'm doing wrong with calculations and from where this overestimation is coming from